# Underlying Variable in a computed property | Swift

Tags: swift

My problem is explained below.
TLDR: my code requires me to use a third variable to represent the value of a computed property. I'm wondering if there is a way to do it with only two variables.

So I have a computed property called `firstNumber` which is a boolean.
Everytime its value is changed, I want to change another variable, `isDecimal`, which is independent of `firstNumber` and has lots of different things that change it.

To do this, when `firstNumber` is set to false I also set `isDecimal` to false. The only issue is that I also need the `firstNumber` boolean to have a value, so I created an underlying boolean called `firstNumberAPI`.

I don't think this is the best way to do what I'm trying to do.
I am wondering if someone can suggest a way to set `isDecimal` when `firstNumber` is changed, without creating a third, `firstNumberAPI` variable.

```
var isDecimal = false
var firstNumberAPI = false

var firstNumber: Bool{
    get{
        return firstNumberAPI
    }
    set{
        firstNumberAPI = newValue
        if newValue==true{
            isDecimal = false
        }
        else{
            isDecimal = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for the `firstNumberAPI` variable. Change `firstNumber` to:

```
var isDecimal = false

var firstNumber: Bool {
    didSet {
        isDecimal = !firstNumber
    }
}
```

See the [Property Observers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254) section of the [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH3-ID0) book for details on `didSet`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Could you possibly explain what "didset" is? I've never seen this syntax before.

Comment: @LeoDabus Of course since that's not right. You need `var firstNumber: Bool = true { ... }`.

Comment: No, you said `firstNumber = false`. The code in answer compiles as-is, without a class, if you simply add `= true` after the `: Bool`.

Comment: @LeoDabus You are making this difficult. You post a bunch of comments which I respond to. Then you delete all of your comments so I deleted mine. Now you post a new set with the same comments. Please stop making me repeat myself. Thanks. If you put the code from my answer, as-is, inside a class, the code compiles as-is as long as you set `firstNumber` in an `init` method or your add the `= true`. Again, like I said the first time around, none of this is relevant to the question.

Comment: @LeoDabus Do what you want. There's nothing to edit. Believe it or not, people are smart enough to read an answer and understand what to do. It's not meant to be copy and paste. It's meant to answer the question asked. And I've addressed your issues in the comments.